# Skip tags in Python HTMLParser to retrieve data

Tags: python, html

This question is related to the utility [googler](https://github.com/jarun/googler).

To retrieve the abstract, currently we use:

```
def abstract_start(self, tag, attrs):
    if tag == 'span' and 'st' in self.classes(attrs):
    self.start_populating_textbuf()
    return 'abstract_text'
```

This works fine when the data is of the format:

```
<span class="st"><em>3 hours</em> of some of the most relaxing music around, with added spa water sounds.<wbr> Ideal peaceful background ...</span>
```

However, if the data is received in the following format (multiple `span` tags, but fixed in number):

```
<span class="st"><span class="f"><span class="nobr">10 Jun 2014</span> - <span class="nobr">179 min</span> - <span class="nobr">Uploaded by Meditation Relax Music</span></span>
                                                    <br><b>3 HOURS Best Relaxing Music</b> &#39;Romantic <b>Piano</b>&quot; Background <b>Music</b> for Stress ... 3:03 <b>...</b>
                                                    </span>
```

this doesn't work. Is there any way to skip the inner 4 `span` tags (plus the `br` tag) and retrieve the data:

```
<b>3 HOURS Best Relaxing Music</b> &#39;Romantic <b>Piano</b>&quot; Background <b>Music</b> for Stress ... 3:03 <b>...</b>
```

This is required for an optimization we are trying where the data is received in the multiple `span` tag format. Any help is much appreciated.

We can go for multi-level `span` tag checks but we are looking for something simpler, given that the text still belongs to the enclosing `<span class="st">`.

Comment: Could you please show the complete code you have so far? Thanks.

Comment: Please feel free to take a look [here](https://github.com/jarun/googler/blob/master/googler#L788).